# How to SortBy Last and in Reverse order?

Tags: sorting

I am looking at the two functions `SortBy` and `ReverseSort`.

```
SortBy[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 2}}, Last]
```

> > {{2, 3, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}

How do I sort this by the last element, but in the reverse order? I want to get this:

> > {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3, 1}}

Comment: may be I am missing your question. Is this what you want?
 `Reverse@SortBy[{{1,2,3},{2,3,1},{3,1,2},{2,2}},Last]` which gives `{{1,2,3},{3,1,2},{2,2},{2,3,1}}`

Answer (score 9):

If you don't care about the ordering of `{3, 1, 2}` and `{2, 2}`, do this:

```
SortBy[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 2}}, Minus @* Last]
   {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 1}}
```

Otherwise, add a second sorting criterion; e.g.

```
SortBy[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 2}}, {Minus @* Last, Minus @* Length}]
   {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3, 1}}
```

or just wrap the sorting criterion in a list (per Alan):

```
SortBy[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 2}}, {Minus @* Last}]
   {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3, 1}}
```

Comment: I think `SortBy[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 2}}, {Minus@*Last}]` will ensure a stable sort.

Comment: Ah, right. Let me add that note.

Answer (score 7):

Using:

```
l = {{2, 3, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}};
```

One option, just using [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sort.html):

```
Sort[l, Last[#2] < Last[#1] &]
```

Another option, using [`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html) and [`Reverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reverse.html):

```
Reverse@SortBy[l, Last]
```

I'm not completely sure about [`ReverseSort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReverseSort.html) (my version of Mathematica does not have it), but I imagine something like this would be at least a start (not too sure about "tie" cases, or how concerned you are with them):

```
ReverseSort[l, Last[#1] < Last[#2] &]
```

Not an expert on this, so anyone should feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'd expect `SortBy` to be considerably faster than `Sort` with a custom comparison function (because each custom comparison requires a Mathematica evaluation)